# Installing a package (grace) using yum on CentOS

Tags: yum, xmgrace

Linux question: I want to install a package named 'grace' on CentOS 7.

Yum install grace fails ("No package grace available.")

The grace web page lists a debian package but apt-get isn't available on CentOS and I've read posts discouraging installing apt-get on RPM systems like CentOS. But there is a Ubuntu package available for grace (http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/grace). On my machine, uname -i returns x86_64, which is not among the listed architectures. So...

1) Will a Ubuntu (i386) package work on my CentOS x86_64 architecture?
2) How do I get yum to find the package?
3) Is a better (x86_64) package for grace available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple : Add the epel.repo https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL : **Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux** → → 
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm

Then : # `yum install grace` , and you get a genuine EL7 package, grace-5.1.23

Comment: Heh. I did 'yum provides' on one of my Centos7 boxes before I answered his question and I hadn't noticed the package right at the start of the results. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Is it this package here?

http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xmgrace

You could download the appropriate RPM file for your system and use 'yum localinstall nameofpackagefile'